# Trying to apply Solver with Macros

Tags: excel, vba, solver

So I already added the Solver Reference on my Active Module.

I used this code to get familiar with Macros for Solver but dosent work, dosent even give me an error.
¿Can you guy tip me pls?

```
Sub SolverMacro()
    
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:="$R$2", MaxMinVal:=0, ValueOf:=0.1, ByChange:="$I$2", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve True
    
End Sub
```

My objective is to make cell R2 10% by changing cell I2. With out Macros it works perfectlly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer:  So I thought MaxMinVal was when you wanted to insert a Max value or a Min value, but actually it is for choosing a parameter, like this:

MaxMinVal: This is an optional parameter. Below are numbers and specifiers:

- 1 = Maximize
- 2 = Minimize
- 3 = for Match a specific value

Source: https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-solver/

So my code shpuld have been like this:

```
Sub SolverMacro()
    
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:="$R$2", MaxMinVal:="3", ValueOf:="0.1", ByChange:="$I$2", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve True
    
End Sub
```